# Travelling back from Japan to EU

Tags: europe, japan

I'm going to bring some presents along like magnets for the fridge, maybe some clothing and some stuff like sweets from Japan back to the European Union.

Is there anything in particular I should take care of like taxes or anything of that sorts, when bringing stuff back with me via plane?

Comment: Do you with 'Europe' mean an EU country? Non-EU countries in Europe have very different regulations.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo yes as an European Union citizen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant ruling are customs rules for import. Relevant limitations are on value

- The maximum value of all imported goods should be less than 430€
- Especially for Clothing you should avoid counterfeit cloths
- For sweets that's typically no issue unless it includes meat or other animal products

You haven't mentioned those, but also for cigarettes/tobacco products, alcohol,  protected animals (ivory etc.) restrictions or custom fees exist.

German customs have a site listing all restrictions in detail: http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Duties-and-taxes/Travellers-allowances/travellers-allowances_node.html (those rules are rules of the European Customs Union, thus should also be applicable with other points of entry)